# problems with a regex in python?

Tags: python

I have a big string like this:

```
está estar VAIP3S0 0.999201
en en SPS00 1
el el DA0MS0 1
punto punto NCMS000 1
medio medio AQ0MS0 0.314286
. . Fp 1

Es ser VSIP3S0 1
de de SPS00 0.999984
color color NCMS000 1
blanco blanco AQ0MS0 0.598684
y y CC 0.999962
tiene tener VMIP3S0 1
carga carga NCFS000 0.952569
frontal frontal AQ0CS0 0.657209
, , Fc 1
no no RN 0.902728
estaba estar VAII1S0 0.5
equilibrada equilibrar VMP00SF 1
. . Fp 1'''
```

I would like to extract the the ids that have the `RN` `VA_ _ _ _ _` and `VMP_ _ _ _ _` where _ are free characters of the string(id) and the second word of the line for example, for the above list:

```
[(no RN, estar VAII1S0, equilibrar VMP00SF)]
```

This is what I all ready tried:

```
weird_triple = re.findall(r'^(\w+)\s.+\s(RN)\s[0-9.]+\n^(.+)\s.+\s(VA)', big_string, re.M)
print "\n This is the weird triple\n", weird_triple
print "\n This is the striped weird triple\n", [x[::2] for x in weird_triple]
```

This is the output:

```
 This is the weird triple

[('no', 'RN', 'estaba', 'VA')]

 This is the striped weird triple
[('no', 'estaba')]
```

Comment: Can you give us a minimal case of test string and desired output?

Comment: This is the desired output: `[(no RN, estar VAII1S0, equilibrar VMP00SF)]` and this is my minimal case of test:`^(\w+)\s.+\s(RN)\s[0-9.]+\n^(.+)\s.+\s(VA)` thanks

Comment: By minimal case I don't mean the pattern you tried, but a short test string, i.e. the string you're extracting it from.

Comment: @newWithPython from that description, I'd recommend doing `re.findall(r"(.*)", "no RN, estar VAII1S0, equilibrar VMP00SF")` ;)

Comment: I edited guys, thanks I forgot to specify the string

Comment: Are you looking for something like https://regex101.com/r/jY1bW8/1?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I tried that but I get nothing, thanks!

Comment: What do you mean *"get nothing"*? Are you using the correct flags?

Comment: I do the following:`weird_triple = re.findall(r'(\w+\sRN).*?(\w+\sVA\w{5}).*?(\w+\sVM\w{5})', big_string, re.M)
print "\n This is the weird triple\n"
print weird_triple`and I get:`This is the weird triple
[]`

Comment: So the answer to *"are you using the correct flags"* is "no"... See https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify your regex as follows:

```
>>> re.findall(r'(\w+\s+RN).*?(\w+\s+VA\w+).*?(\w+\s+VM\w+)', big_string, re.S)
[('no RN', 'estar VAII1S0', 'equilibrar VMP00SF')]
```

**Note:** The `re.M` flag causes `^` and `$` to match the begin/end of each line while the `re.S` flag allows the dot to match across newline sequences.

Comment: It does match those in that order